# variables in expressjs views

Tags: node.js, express

I want to make session variables (or any others) usable in the views without repeating myself all over again.

I came up with this:

```
  res.render('index', viewVariables(req, res, params, {});
```

And the `viewVariables` function:

```
function viewVariables(req, res, params, options) {
  var returnObject = options || {locals:{}};
  var locals = {
    currentUser: req.currentUser ? req.currentUser : false
  };
  returnObject.locals = mergeObjects(locals, returnObject.locals, true);
  return returnObject;
};
```

Thats not working in the latest expressjs version (different render method).

Is there a simpler or more elegent solution for that? (well I'm sure there is!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at dynamichelpers?

From the website:

```
app.dynamicHelpers(obj)
```

> Registers dynamic view helpers.
>   Dynamic view helpers are simply
>   functions which accept req, res, and
>   are evaluated against the Server
>   instance before a view is rendered.
>   The return value of this function
>   becomes the local variable it is
>   associated with.

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  session: function(req, res){
    return req.session;
  }
});
```

Most of the times I like to make it a function instead. This way it will be only called when you call the function in your views.

Answer (score 0):

**Express v2.x**

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  session: function(req, res){
    return req.session;
  }
});
```

**Express v.3**

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.locals.session = req.session;
});
```